# Pushing a branch to UPSTREAM after accidentally

Tags: git, github

So there are 2 remotes configured.

- My Fork(ORIGIN) -> origin    `git@github.com:Anirudh/TestRepo.git`
- The main REPO from which my fork was made.(UPSTREAM) -> upstream     https://github.com:Anirudh/TestRepo.git

I made made a feature branch with no remote pre-configured and accidentally pushed it to upstream

```
git push upstream
```

Now the branch is there on the UPSTREAM which is undesired so I wanna actually push it to origin and the delete the branch in upstream

what's the safest way to do it?

Comment: Your two repos are the same. The only difference is the protocol used to talk with them.

Comment: how does that help?

Comment: Well, you told us you forked your repo, and thus have two repos, but you have just one. So the question doesn't make any sense. Since upstream and origin are the same repo, pushing on one pushes on the other, and vice-versa.

Comment: @JBNizet WHAT made you come to the conclusion of one repo? please expand.

Comment: The URL of your fork is `git@github.com:Anirudh/TestRepo.git`. The URL of your main repo is `https://github.com:Anirudh/TestRepo.git`. Except for the protocol (git for the first one, https for the second one), they have the same URL. So it's a unique repo. Or there's something I don't understand in your question. Anyway, you're asking how to delete a remote branch, and that is answered by Code Wizard.

Comment: dude, before you blindly Criticise/Downvote, read the question properly first. I mentioned ```2 remotes``` NOT ```2 Different Repos``` which are rather different versions of the same repository but when you ```push``` you push to a particular version of the repo.

Comment: No, that's not what you did. You said you had a "Fork" (I'm quoting here). Forking a repo consists in creating another repo. Not just in declaring a new remote. And no, two remotes are not "different versions of the same repo", and no, pushing to a remote doesn't "push to a particular version of the repo". If you have one repo, known under two different remote names, whatever remote you use to push, you'll push to that single, unique repo. So please, stop being agressive, and consider the possibility that you might just be wrong,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its much more simple than you think:

```
# create a new branch with the desired name:
git checkout -b <branch name>

# push the desired branch
git push origin <branch name>

# delete the wrong branch from upstream
git push upstream --delete <branch to delete>
```

---

As a best practice you should always **add** the desired branch name to pull/push. Read on why.

Here is the git v2.0 release notes which explain the change in the way git treat push (simple vs matching). This was updated in git v2.0 to fix the default `git push` behavior.

Prior to git v2.0 when you executed `git push` it would have pushed all your changed branches (**all** and not only the current branch).

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional **`matching`** semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the `simple` semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   `matching` semantics, you can set the variable to `matching`, for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.**strong text**

Comment: this was helpful, thanks for understanding my question and a clear explanation.

Comment: Cool, glad to help you out.